# Center 2 DIV's on a page where each DIV takes up 45%

Tags: css, html

I have two `<div>`'s and each one is set to be 45% of the width of their container. Is there a way to center the `<div>`'s so that they have the same amount of space on the left and right sides in the container and also have space in between them.

At first I just made each `<div>` 50% and had `padding: 0px 25px;` on the container so that they wouldn't run from edge to edge. The problem is that the right side of the left `<div>` runs right up against left side of the right `<div>` and I would like to put some space between them.

When I attempted to put space between them either using `margin` or `padding`, the right `<div>` would get moved down below the left instead of staying beside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the margin-right of the first element to a percentage width:

```
.first {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

.second {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
}
```

See the JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/1nkaa05z/

If you need some space on the outer edges of each element, you can set the margin-left of the first element to 2%, the margin-right of the second element to 2%, and the margin-right of the first element (the divider) to 6%. As long as the remaining width doesn't exceed 10%, the second element should not drop to a new line.

Comment: Thanks this works great. I was trying to do all kinds of math, but this is so much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the center tag

```
`<center>
<div1></div>
<div2></div>
</center>
`
```

Comment: the center tag is not supported in HTML5 and it is recommended to use CSS instead and `<center>` only centers the text and not the actual `<div>`s

Comment: He didn't mention he was using HTML5, I didn't assume he was and I suppose if he wants to use CSS and have two divs centered with 45% width each, try putting 5% margin left on div1 and 5% margin right on div2

Comment: putting 5% margin on each side doesn't account for allowing there to be space in between the `<div>`s

Comment: @AtlasBowler center is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most recommended way to build layouts is to use a grid.

```
 <div class="grid">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="content">Element 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="content">Element 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid{
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 0;
}
.column{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
    background-color: yellow;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 0 2.5%;
}

.first {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-right:2.5%;
    margin-left:2.5;
}

.content{
    background-color: gold;
}

.second {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

First you create container (`.grid`) ant set font-size to 0. Next you put inside as many columns as you want. You decide on with and gutter. In this example with is 45%, gutter will be 100%-(2*45%) divided by 4 (or 2 if you want gutter only in the middle). Put that value in to the padding `.column` . Next you have to reset font-size. And this is end just put your content in to it.

https://jsfiddle.net/1nkaa05z/2/

All other stuff like table, table-cell (table but in css. how the hell this is better?), floats, centre etc are obsolete now days. This or flex box is is the way how we should do it.